# How to run gitlab pipeline with desired title?

Tags: gitlab-ci, cicd

Currently gitlab pipelines which I execute show me the last commit message as it's description. But when I need to search for some specific pipeline it becomes time consuming. Can we pass some title to pipeline before running it? If so can u please share some sample example.

Comment: This sounds like a bit of an XY problem. IT sounds like its your commit messages that are lacking the details. As far as i know there is no option to set a message for a pipeline

Comment: @ChrisDoyle in case if pipeline has both QA and test deployment stages and last commit is with some configuration change description and I want to trigger only QA deployment alone, in such scenario my last commi message is not going to make clear regarding what purpose I ran it. So , having some pipeline name/title will be very helpful